# Update nested JSON value in SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-update, sql-server-2017

I have following Json in my table:

```
{ 
   "filterCriteria":[ 
      { 
         "fieldId":"abc",
         "filterData":[ 
            { 
               "values":[ 
                  { 
                     "id":1,
                     "value":"1",
                     "text":"1"
                  },
                  { 
                     "id":2,
                     "value":"2",
                     "text":"2"
                  }
               ],
               "filterType":"equals"
            }
         ]
      },
      { 
         "fieldId":"def",
         "filterData":[ 
            { 
               "values":[ 
                  { 
                     "id":3,
                     "value":"3",
                     "text":"3"
                  },
                  { 
                     "id":4,
                     "value":"4",
                     "text":"4"
                  }
               ],
               "filterType":"equals"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

and I want to update value node based on index of particular field Id.

Let's take an example: if I want to update value node of field `id="abc"` and `id=1`, then I have to write this code:

```
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(max) = Above mentioned JSON

SELECT
    JSON_MODIFY(@JSON,'$."filterCriteria"[0].filterData[0].values[0].value', 'Hey');
```

But if I have to update based on fetching index on some filters then I'm unable to figure out how to do it. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: fieldId="abc", not id="abc" I believe is what you meant

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to parse the input JSON, find the indexes and modify the JSON. Note, that you need SQL Server 2017+ to provide a variable as the value of `path` in `JSON_MODIFY()` call:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{"filterCriteria":[{"fieldId":"abc","filterData":[{"values":[{"id":1,"value":"1","text":"1"},{"id":2,"value":"2","text":"2"}],"filterType":"equals"}]},{"fieldId":"def","filterData":[{"values":[{"id":3,"value":"3","text":"3"},{"id":4,"value":"4","text":"4"}],"filterType":"equals"}]}]}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(
   @json,
   CONCAT('$."filterCriteria"[', id1, '].filterData[', id2, '].values[', id3, '].value'),
   'Hey'
)
FROM (
   SELECT j1.[key] AS id1, j3.[key] AS id2, j4.[key] AS id3
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.filterCriteria') j1
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value], '$') WITH (
      fieldId varchar(3) '$.fieldId',
      filterData nvarchar(max) '$.filterData' AS JSON
   ) j2
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j2.filterData, '$') j3 
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j3.[value], '$.values') j4
   CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (j3.[value], '$.values') WITH (
      id int '$.id'
   ) j5
   WHERE (j2.fieldId = 'abc') AND (j5.id = 1)
) t

SELECT @json
```

Result (based on your example JSON):

```
{ 
   "filterCriteria":[ 
      { 
         "fieldId":"abc",
         "filterData":[ 
            { 
               "values":[ 
                  { 
                     "id":1,
                     "value":"Hey",
                     "text":"1"
                  },
                  { 
                     "id":2,
                     "value":"2",
                     "text":"2"
                  }
               ],
               "filterType":"equals"
            }
         ]
      },
      { 
         "fieldId":"def",
         "filterData":[ 
            { 
               "values":[ 
                  { 
                     "id":3,
                     "value":"3",
                     "text":"3"
                  },
                  { 
                     "id":4,
                     "value":"4",
                     "text":"4"
                  }
               ],
               "filterType":"equals"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Zhorov but i need to update the resulted json in table and filterdata may have multiple values.